# Why can't this function be drawn in this interval?

Tags: plotting

```
In[1]:= Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_?NumericQ] = 
 Piecewise[{{-x, x < 0}, {1/2 f[x - f[x - 1]], x >= 0}}]
```

[image]

Why can't this function be drawn in this interval?

```
Plot[f[x], {x, -1, 5}]
```

Comment: `Plot[f[x], {x, -2, 2.9}]`

Comment: `f` calls itself and it enters a very long recursive loop. E.g. `f[3]`. It's not a plotting issue. It's an evaluation issue.